# what does this linux command do: "cd !!:1"

Tags: linux, cd

In linux command cd, after make a dir, I can use "cd !!:1" to enter it, but what exactly does **!!:1** mean, I can't search it by google, because it include special chars.

Comment: The double exclamation repeats the previous command. I would guess that the :1 pulls the second part of the previous command, as opposed to the entire thing—but I don't know that with certainty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!!` is short hand for the previous command. The `:1` goes to the second parameter in the command, which in your previous command was the directory name. 
One of my favorite command-line shortcuts is `sudo !!`

Answer (score 5):

That will change directory to the first argument of the previous command

For example

```
% ls foo bar
% cd !!:1
```

is equivalent to

```
% ls foo bar
% cd foo
```

Also  `!!:0`  gives you the actual command (less arguments), `!!:2` the second argument, `!!:$` the last argument, and `!!` the whole command line.